# Adding collapsible legend box to Mapbox and features no longer click-able

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl

So, first I started with this map: https://codepen.io/melissad34/pen/mNGjKR

It works exactly the way I want it to work.

Then I added a collapsible sidebar: https://codepen.io/melissad34/pen/LYYrLKN

And now the trails features aren't clickable as they were on the first version.
I had to change the z-index of the divs to get the sidebar to show over the map div, so I wonder if that's why, but I assume that shouldn't be an issue because it's not like the sidebar covers the entire map.

What is causing this?

Answer (score 2):

That's not an issue about mapbox at all. It's caused by script error. As console shows, the line number 31 of JS, it uses `legend` but it's not declared. You should set `legend` as ID on div element.

```
<div class="row row-offcanvas" id="legend">
  <div class="sidebar-offcanvas sidebar">
  ....
```